# How to change default back screen in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How can I specify react navigation to go back to a specific screen when i press the back button in my device  instead of going to the original previous screen in Stack Navigator
Example : I have an app where after placing an order in a ConfirmOrder screen it navigates to OrderPlaced Screen but when I press the back button I don't want o be navigated back to ConfirmOrder instead I want it to navigate to some other specific screen like "Home"

Comment: implement `react router dom`, do you want me to post the example code?

Comment: You can use navigation.reset in OrderPlaced screen, or navigate with navigation.replace in ConfirmOrder screen

Answer (score 1):

Use `navigation.navigate()` to go to a specific screen and place it on the stack
so you can go back to it when you go to the next screen by doing `navigation.goBack()` use `navigation.replace()` to completely replace that screen in the stack

```js
navigation.navigate("Home")
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please provide a little bit more information about how to implement it, I am new to React Native so

Comment: So navigation gets passed as a prop to all its children. So when a child component gets it as a prop you can access it by doing `props.navigation.navigate("Home")`. On other hand you can deconstruct when it gets passed  and that lets you do `navigation.navigate("Home")` . But I don't want to confuse you so learn about deconstructing a javascript object on the web